# Google Maps JavaScript API library must be loaded - convert solution for react functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This solution (below) was given and fixes the problem of checking PlacesAutocomplete is loaded first before trying to load it and causing an error(within a class component), but I'm struggling to convert it to use in a functional component with react hooks as I can't access window.initMap.

```
state = {
  gmapsLoaded: false,
}

initMap = () => {
  this.setState({
    gmapsLoaded: true,
  })
}

componentDidMount () {
  window.initMap = this.initMap
  const gmapScriptEl = document.createElement(`script`)
  gmapScriptEl.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=SECRET_EATING&libraries=places&callback=initMap`
  document.querySelector(`body`).insertAdjacentElement(`beforeend`, gmapScriptEl)
}

render () {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.gmapsLoaded && (
        <PlacesAutocomplete />
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

was trying:

```
const [gmapsLoaded,setgmapsLoaded ] = useState(false)



initMap = () => {
    
      setgmapsLoaded(true)

  }


  useEffect(() => {
    window.initMap = this.initMap
  const gmapScriptEl = document.createElement(`script`)
  gmapScriptEl.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAmlRtE1Ggrzz-iSUAWGIcm0mmi7GXbKtI&callback=initMap"
  document.querySelector(`body`).insertAdjacentElement(`beforeend`, gmapScriptEl)
  });
```

but to no avail

Comment: Have you tried `window.initMap = initMap`?  Functional components don't have a `this`.

Comment: thanks jmargolisvt though this still does not solve the problem.

Comment: jmargolisvt thanks you were actually correct , i just didn't add const to the initmap also

Answer (score 0):

I also tried this though it doesn't work, it solves it from crashing though it won't load the suggestions on the screen found inside PlacesAutoComplete and just keeps saying "Loading..."

```
 import React, { useContext, useState , useEffect} from "react";

const initMap = () => {
    
      setgmapsLoaded(true)

  }


  useEffect(() => {

    if (gmapsLoaded === false) {
    window.initMap = initMap
  const gmapScriptEl = document.createElement(`script`)
  gmapScriptEl.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAmlRtE1Ggrzz-iSUAWGIcm0mmi7GXbKtI&callback=initMap"
  document.querySelector(`body`).insertAdjacentElement(`beforeend`, gmapScriptEl)
    }
  });



    {gmapsLoaded && (
    <PlacesAutocomplete
        value={address}
        onChange={setAddress}
        onSelect={handleSelect}
      >
        {({ getInputProps, suggestions, getSuggestionItemProps, loading }) => (
          <div>

<p> latitude: {coordinates.lat}</p>
<p> longitude: {coordinates.lng}</p>
<p> Address: {address}</p>


            <input
              {...getInputProps({
                placeholder: 'Search Places ...',
                className: 'location-search-input',
              })}
            />
            <div className="autocomplete-dropdown-container">
              {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
              {suggestions.map(suggestion => {
                const className = suggestion.active
                  ? 'suggestion-item--active'
                  : 'suggestion-item';
                // inline style for demonstration purpose
                const style = suggestion.active
                  ? { backgroundColor: '#fafafa', cursor: 'pointer' }
                  : { backgroundColor: '#ffffff', cursor: 'pointer' };
                return (
                  <div
                    {...getSuggestionItemProps(suggestion, {
                      className,
                      style,
                    })}
                  >
                    <span>{suggestion.description}</span>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </PlacesAutocomplete>
    )
            }
```